# How to track memory usage of the networking subsystem in the Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, performance, networking, linux-kernel, operating-system

Is there a way to determine how much physical memory is being used by the network subsystem in the Linux kernel at any given point in time? I understand the per-connection memory limits can be specified via sysctl. But is there a tool to peek inside the TCP/IP stack and ask it how much buffered data it has per connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try: `ss -m`?  The documentation of the reported values seems scarce but you can make educated guesses based on their full names defined in [linux/sock_diag.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/uapi/linux/sock_diag.h).

Comment: There's more info on what the memory stats returned by ss mean [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33855/kernel-socket-structure-and-tcp-diag).